# Primeira letra maiúscula de uma Series

Tags: python

Quero fazer uma `def` de primeira letra maíuscula, consegui fazer com lambda e laço for, mas queria fazer uma função raiz e ta dando erro, o que está errado?

```py
ser = pd.Series(['how', 'to', 'kick', 'ass?'])

def maiusculo(x):
    for x in ser:
        return ser.map(x.title())

maiusculo(ser)
```

Comment: O `.map` dispensa o uso do `for`, seu return deveria ser somente `.map` com a função `lambda` (que você não está utilizando), sugiro pesquisar como ela funciona. 
[Lambda function inside map pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303244/lambda-function-inside-map-pandas), [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não precisa nada disso. A série já possui formas de você manipular o conteúdo como string e utilizar os métodos nativos:

```
>>> result = ser.str.title()
>>> print(result)

0     How
1      To
2    Kick
3    Ass?
dtype: object
```

Isto é, ao usar `ser.str.title()` será criado uma nova série com o resultado do método `str.title` para cada valor da série original.